# method to get raw data of streaming

Tags: sony, sony-smarteyeglass

I want porting my application for android phone what analyze live streaming to smarteyeglass.

I use raw data `(YUV420SP) onPreviewFrame(byte[] data,Camera camera)/setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer()` in android SDK,
and I found `"onCameraReceived(CameraEvent event)/SmartEyeglassEventListener"` in SmartEyeGlass SDK, but `event.getData()` return JPEG data.

Is there method to get raw data in SmartEyeGlass SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately is not possible to get the raw data, only JPEG data.  What is the reason for wanting raw data instead of JPEG?

Comment: Humm...I checked event.getData() in onCameraReceived when CAMERA_MODE_JPG_STREAM_HIGH_RATE,CAMERA_MODE_JPG_STREAM_LOW_RATE and CAMERA_MODE_STILL by using SampleCameraExtention, but all lossy JPEG YUV422 data. Do you mean that is raw data?

Comment: Sorry, I checked with our team and I was wrong about the raw data -- it is only JPEG as you have noted above.  Edited my answer above.